# Host a hidden service on a different port and access from clearnet

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, web-proxy

I have an hidden service hosted on port 8080 (cause port 80 is busy on another service) and I'd like to allow people visit it through web proxies like onion.sh.

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to use different ports on clearnet proxies like onion.sh.

The hidden service is created with a docker cause I'm not really into it, but if there are better ways I'm here to learn (only requirement: I need at least a full lamp stack on the hidden service)

Thank you!

Comment: You're running two web servers on the same onion service? Can you split them up into two different onion services, each running on port 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, port 80 is blocked by another, unrelated service you can't or won't change. But are you able to change the config of that service? So you could set it to bind only to your clearnet ip port 80 (and not all interfaces / at least not localhost), so that you can set your onion service to listen on localhost port 80 and then configure Tor to relay your onion service to localhost:80 (assuming tor and your onion service run on the same machine / within the same container).
That way, you would have both at port 80, but at different interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, I did something very similar and it worked like a charm :)

Comment: You're welcome.